# How do I implement Data Retrieval from a website in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, data-mining, data-storage

I want to write a program in Objective-c that grabs some sports stats off a website and stores them in such a way that I can run some statistical analysis on them. I have a little experience with objective-c but have been working with java more recently and have forgotten a lot of the basic organization of the objective-c language.

I was wondering if someone could recommend:

the best way to store data for this purpose?

the best way to go about getting data from the website and what classes I will need to override/implement to do this?
     more specifically: I want to download the website's contents, and sieve through the HTML code, but am not sure how to go about this.

I just sort of need a starting point because I am a little overwhelmed right now. Thanks in advance to this helpful and thoughtful community, which I look forward to being a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for most data storage, its worth using core data, even if you don't need to store it on disc, as it can be very convenient for designing the data model, and gets a lot of the data management stuff out of the way.

as for getting the data off of the website, there are a lot of things that affect this. is the website within your control?  or does the website have any kind of API? or is it a case of scraping the website, and processing at the iPhone side of things?

Comment: well, my thought was that I could just sieve through the html and pick the data out of the table that its displayed in, unless there is some better way of doing this.

Comment: is this a personal project or one you plan on releasing/selling? if you are planning on releasing, then be aware that even a slight change in format could break parsing.  if they have a public api then use that if possible, as it reduces the chances of a breakage significantly. if you have control of the site, maybe setup a page to output json, or you could generate a plist on the server that could be downloaded by the app. also, have a look at in-memory stores for core data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something more than [`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC)?

Comment: I want to go through the website and grab certain stats and then create a data set. I was thinking maybe just put them in a plist, but I wasn't sure if there was something better for the purpose.

Comment: Well, that all depends on lots of other things.  What format is the data in on the website?  What format do you intend to use to store it locally?  etc.  Your question is too broad if it's "how should I handle my data in my application?"

Comment: Sorry about that, the data is stored in an html table on the website. So I figured I would run through the html code and grab the numbers. And I guess I'm asking about the best way to store it locally.

Comment: If you choose to use a plist, you could use [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:] or [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:] (depending on the structure of the plist) to directly create a dictionary or array.